# Typescript nested forEach as decorator

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-decorator

We have rather complicated api that should be nested with multiple parameters.
Now tests looks like callback hell

```
[true, false, null].forEach(customer => {
   [true, false, null].forEach(sale => {
    it('test', ()=> {
       // Do something with customer and sale
     })
  })
})
```

Tests can have up to 10 parameters and all should be checked.

I am thinking of switching to typescript. So I wonder if there is a possibility to rewrite test to something like

```
let customer: []
@param(customer, [true, false, null])
it('test', ()=>{})
```

So that the functionality stays the same.
Is it any way for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorators are applicable to classes only. `it` is regular function and cannot be used with a decorator. `it` cannot be unnested this case because it should receive `customer` value that is specific to this test, and this is done in nested function scope.

This is not what callback hell usually means. The level of nesting of `forEach` callbacks is strictly determined by loop nesting and doesn't complicate control flow. In case this is a concern, loops can be rewritten with any other loop structure:

```
for (const customer of [true, false, null]) {
  ...
}
```

Jest API has [`each`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) that allows to provide data in a loop in more concise way.

Comment: Thanks. Jest each accepts tuples and it doesn't cover all possible variants for 2 variables. Also on 26.6 it has a bug. That's why I decided to go with forEach or for of loop.